# Extract table name from DDL File

Tags: sql, linux, unix, awk, sed

I have DDL File and using grep command I can able to extract the below line using the command `cat employee.sql | grep -i 'TABLE'`

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_EMPLOYEE(
       ID VARCHAR(255),
       NAME VARCHAR(150),
       ADDRESS VARCHAR(150),
       STREET VARCHAR(150),
       SUBURB VARCHAR(100),
       STATE VARCHAR(100)
        );
```

`CREATE TABLE TEMP_EMPLOYEE(`

I want to extract the just TABLE name further from the above string. Can some one help how. I've used `sed` but printing the same string.

Comment: added ddl extract sample

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to use GNU grep:

```
grep -Po 'CREATE TABLE \K[^(]*' employee.sql
```

or GNU sed:

```
sed -n 's/CREATE TABLE \(.*\)(/\1/p' employee.sql
```

or awk:

```
awk -F '[( ]' '/CREATE TABLE/ {print $3}' employee.sql
```

Output:

```
TEMP_EMPLOYEE
```